# Delete SharePoint site using Rest API

Tags: http, sharepoint

I am working on deleting a Sharepoint site using the API. I obtain my access token the following way:

```
curl --location 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id={clientId}' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret={clientSecret}' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
```

My access token has the following property when I run it trough [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/):

```json
"roles": [
    "Sites.Selected",
    "Sites.Read.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.Manage.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.Read.All",
    "Sites.FullControl.All"
  ]
```

Now I try to delete a certain SharePoint site by doing the following according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/site-creation-rest#delete-a-modern-site) documentation:

```
curl --location 'https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/sites/{testSite}/_api/SPSiteManager/delete' \
--header 'Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none' \
--header 'odata-version: 4.0' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {bearerToken}' \
--data '{
    "siteId": "{siteId}"
}'
```

When executing this HTTP request I get the following error message:

```json
{
    "error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Should I reqeust the token in a different way or is there a better alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: Dumb question, but where did you specify the method `POST` in your CURL command? `curl -X POST`

Comment: @jleture sorry, this is the curl I copy and pasted from the postman code snippet tab. Both are a POST however.